# How to add a new object to Layout by Java? Android

Tags: java, android

For example, I have an ImageView got by this:

```
public ImageView get_image_by_name(String name)
{
    int image_id = getResources().getIdentifier(name , "drawable", getPackageName());
    return (ImageView)findViewById(image_id);
}
```

Not sure it works at all.

How shall I add it to layout?

Comment: No. This is not how you do this. Your code gives `image_id` the id of a drawable, not of an imageview. Your `findViewById()` call will give a null, even if the previous line doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this function is placed somewhere within `Activity`, you can try this:

```
public ImageView get_image_by_name(String name)
{
    int image_id = getResources().getIdentifier(name , "drawable", getPackageName());
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(image_id));
    return iv;
}
```

You can also change `LayoutParams` to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Layouts all derive from ViewGroup, so they all have a function named addView.  Pass the ImageView to it.

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure it works at all

answer is u are right your current code not work because you are trying to find any drawable resource in current layout as imageView. Change your code as which return u  dynamically created imageView  :

```
public ImageView get_image_by_name(String name)
{
    int image_id = getResources().getIdentifier(name , 
                   "drawable", getPackageName());
    ImageView imageView=new ImageView(Your_Current_Activity.this);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(image_id);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new    
                 LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    return imageView;
}
```